# AppError 404 equivalent in cake 2.0

Tags: cakephp, error-handling, migration

I've recently upgraded my 1.3 cake app to 2.0, and I'm trying to redo my app_error code.

With Cake 1.3, it was simply a case of creating an app_error.php file, putting it in my app root, and overriding the built-in error404() and missingController() actions.

Here is my old 1.3 /app/app_error.php file: http://pastebin.com/beWZD9PJ

It had some code that kicked in when someone arrived at the site with a predefined 'alias' URL, and then it redirected them accordingly.

I just need this to work in Cake2.0, and I see the manual is telling me its all changed, but I can't find a specific case like this. Can anyone help me out, so the error404 code kicks in?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can throw a 404 exception with the following code in your controller in Cake 2:

```
throw new NotFoundException(__('Your error text here'));
```

Then, you just need to have `APP/View/Errors/error400.ctp` present with something relevant to display. Cake includes this by default:

```
<h2><?php echo $name; ?></h2>
<p class="error">
    <strong><?php echo __d('cake', 'Error'); ?>: </strong>
    <?php printf(
        __d('cake', 'The requested address %s was not found on this server.'),
        "<strong>'{$url}'</strong>"
    ); ?>
</p>
<?php
if (Configure::read('debug') > 0 ):
    echo $this->element('exception_stack_trace');
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Where is that element called 'exception_stack_trace' defined? It doesn't seem to appear anywhere in the Cake code-base.

Comment: @geoidesic This question was about Cake 2. The element can be found at https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/2.x/lib/Cake/View/Elements -- no idea about the latest Cake 3 though. I switched to Laravel after Cake 2 so I'm not familiar with the latest releases.

Answer (score 5):

4xx and 5xx errors in CakePHP 2.0 ar now exceptions, thus you need to customize your Exception renderer or handler. Read from this section to the bottom http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#exception-renderer

Comment: I'm going to sound stupid here, I've read all of that, and I'm none the wiser. I can't find any reference to extending error404, its all focused around internal exceptions. I can't see how I can replicate my above example in Cake2.0

Comment: cant edit the above. I found this, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#built-in-exceptions-for-cakephp but no real explanation of how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple.

With cakephp 2, you have to add this function in your AppController:

```
public function appError($error) {
    $this->redirect('/');
}
```

Here, for example we redirect all errors to index page.

Comment: Why on earth would you redirect all errors to the index page?